# Sorting css properties in string for every element of an array using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

How to sort a multidimensional array with the following structure

```
arr[0] = "width:100px;height:200px;"
arr[1] = "color:#FFF;background:none;"
```

I would require the output to be like

```
arr[0] = "height:200px;width:100px;"
arr[1] = "background:none;color:#FFF;"
```

Its more like sorting items inside a given array.
Please help.

Comment: That's not a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: oh ya, its not multidimensional. But Barmar, could you please let me know how to sort this?

Answer (score 5):

Split each string into an array, sort that array, join it back together, and replace the array element with that.

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = arr[i].split(';').sort().join(';').substr(1)+';';
}
```

`substr(1)` and `+';'` are needed because `split` and join expect `;` to be a separator, not terminator. So when we split the original string, the `;` is treated as delimiting an empty element, which gets put at the front of the result.

Comment: @user3409557 Good luck with that. It's more than I'm going to try to solve in a SO answer.